# Formula Field Case Statement that is dependent on a picklist value

Tags: formula, case, picklist, if

I am trying to edit a formula field and make the Case Statement dependent on the value of a picklist, namely an account TYPE. I know an IF statement takes 3 arguments, but the following is the gist of what I am trying to accomplish. If the picklist value TYPE is something else, the CASE statement would change. Is this possible inside a SF formula field? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
IF(
    TEXT(TYPE) = "CURRENT CUSTOMER"
),
CASE(
    TEXT(Sales_Territory__c),
    'Northwest', 'West',
    'Northeast', 'East',
    'West Coast', 'West',
    'International', 'International',
    'Other'
)
```

Comment: Text is much preferred over images, so I've rolled back that edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but because formulas are so limited you'd have really no other option but to duplicate the `CASE()` structure.

ex.

```
IF(
    TEXT(TYPE) = "CURRENT CUSTOMER",
    /* CASE() for when it is "current customer" */
    CASE(
         /* CASE() is one of the functions that can work with picklists directly */
         Sales_Territory__c,
        'Northwest', 'West',
        'Northeast', 'East',
        'West Coast', 'West',
        'International', 'International',
        'Other'
    ),
    /* CASE() for when Type is not "Current Customer" */
    CASE(
        /* Does not need to be the same field as the previous CASE() */
        Sales_Territory__c,
        'other', 'pre-sales',
        'thing', 'in talks',
        'default'
    )
)
```

For more complex arrangements, nesting `CASE()` functions should be possible. However, at that point, you should probably be instead looking into the standard "dependent picklists" feature.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  It kept giving me a syntax error with the comma after "CURRENT CUSTOMER", so I kept trying other options like ISPICKVAL, etc.  I guess it's because I had the parenthesis there but it kept saying I had an extra comma.  Your response worked great.